# Android - Why click the CheckBox does not trigger the ListView's onItemClick?

Tags: android, listview

The problem is: when I click the checkbox, the ListView's OnItemClickListener didn't be triggered.

I Google for answers but can not find a solution.

Can anyone help me? I want to know why this didn't work.

Inside the VacantHouseActivityFragment's onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vacant_house, container, false);

    ListView vacantHouseList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vacant_house_list);
    vancantHouseAdapter = new VacantHouseListAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.vacant_house_list_item,
            new ArrayList<VacantHouse>()
    );
    vacantHouseList.setAdapter(vancantHouseAdapter);
    vacantHouseList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            CheckBox vacantHouseCheckbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.vacant_house_checkbox);
            Log.v("TAG", (String) vacantHouseCheckbox.getText());
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Content of fragment_vacant_house.xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".VacantHouseActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_vacant_house">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vacant_house_list" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Content of vacant_house_list_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New CheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/vacant_house_checkbox"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/vacant_house_rent"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material"
        android:textSize="@dimen/notification_subtext_size"
        android:focusable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add Adapter Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Just add this two properties:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set onCheckChangeListener on your checkbox

```
.
.
.
vacantHouseList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        CheckBox vacantHouseCheckbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.vacant_house_checkbox);
    vacantHouseCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked) {
                    // checkbox is checked now
                    //your logic code here
                } else {
                    // checkbox is unchecked now
                    //your logic code here
                }
            }
          });

        Log.v("TAG", (String) vacantHouseCheckbox.getText());
    }
});
.
.
.
```

Comment: When I click the checkbox I want to trigger the ListView's onItemClickListener is because I want to know how many items have be selected and I need to know the position of the array.

Comment: make a new method(function) and put all your code inside that method and then call that method inside both `onItemClick` and `onCheckChange`

Comment: I need to get the position parameter from the ListView's onItemClickListener, so this way does not work.